# Split a USB into partitions

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive

Not sure if this is even possible but...

Is it possible to partition a USB drive so I can have a partition for a Live install of Linux and then a partition for storing files on?

Comment: As there is no accepted answer for the duplicate question, I do not know if a deletion for duplicate is the best process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though the data partition might not be automatically mounted/visible in the Linux/live environment. That being said you can always mount it yourself.

Infact if you use FAT or NTFS for the data partition, you should be able to use it in Windows as well.